# moving through the doc, caret staying centered

Tags: navigation

I move around using the arrows ←↓↑→, never really got used to the hjkl thing. I know I'm supposed to use the hjkl thing.

When hitting ↓, it reaches a point where the caret is on the lower side of the display, until I hit some ↑ hits.

Most of the time I need more context down. How do you move the doc down while not moving the caret?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for [`:h 'scrolloff'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27scrolloff%27):

```
'scrolloff' 'so'    number  (default 0)
            global
    Minimal number of screen lines to keep above and below the cursor.
```

So you can add something like this in your `.vimrc`:

```
set scrolloff=10
```

Comment: By not moving the caret I didn't mean _leave the caret in the same document line_ but _leave the caret in the same terminal line_. In `:h scrolling` `CTRL-D` matches, but defaults to half a screen and I need only one line. I read it can be feed a `[count]`, but I didn't understand how to feed it.

Comment: @uprego Oh you mean something like [`:h 'scrolloff'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27scrolloff%27) to always have some lines between the cursor and the border of the window?

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `CTRL-e` and `CTRL-y` to move the view, while not moving the cursor.

At the end of your file, you can use `CTRL-e` until the last line of the document is at the first line of the page.

Comment: I shouldn't have edited my answer but that is what I first suggested to OP but they clarified that it wasn't what they were looking for. Anyway that's still two pretty useful commands.

Comment: Everything in Vim is useful! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want your cursor at the middle, you can use this mapping:

```
nnoremap <silent> yoz :let &scrolloff=999-&scrolloff<cr>
```

This will switch your `scrolloff` option between the value you set (default is `0`) and a very large one. The latter means your cursor stays centred.